# Bootloading settings for ARM Cortex M0 on Keil MDK v5.25

Tags: bootloader, arm

I am trying to do bootloading on Cortex M0 with another program flashed to a certain area in FLASH memory. (e.g. bootloader starts with address 0x08000000 and target program starts with address 0x08001000)

I have two Keil MDK v5.25 projects, one with **target program** and the other **bootloader**.

When I compile and flash the **target program**, and then compile and enter debug mode for the **bootloader**, the functionality works fine. However, I want to just enter debug mode in one setting (i.e. just enter debug mode from **bootloader** project and try to access **target program**) to load both programs to dedicated area of FLASH memory. How can I do that with Keil v5.25 settings?

Now I have added .ini files in Debug and Utilities tab in Options for Target, but I cannot enter debug mode after compile (flash upload failed). Is there any settings required to do this bootloader on Cortex M0?
Thanks!